# Хочу заменить определённую ячейку в таблице

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, база-данных, sqlite

Вот например таблица:

| Деньги | Доход |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 15 |

Нужно сделать так, что бы деньги стали 25, при этом не удаляя строку в таблице

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем sqlite3 и напишите SQL запрос с инструкцией UPDATE. Если непонятно о чем я изучите документацию библиотеки sqlite3. Пример:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('название файла с бд.db')
with con:
    con.execute("UPDATE <table name> SET Деньги = 25 where <условия по выбору строки из таблицы>")
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло!

Comment: @Promed Отлично). Тогда поставьте галочку напротив ответа.